# SET DATESTYLE TO 'European'; in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I'm doing MySQL exercises and I found some of PostgreSQL, and there is a part where before entering the data to the newly created tables, enter that command, `SET DATESTYLE TO 'European'`; I tried to put it in MySQL but it does not recognize it, what would be its equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql` store all the dates in the same style. Internally this is three bytes that are expanded to the `YYYY-MM-DD`. You can convert this format to the any desired form by DATE_FORMAT() function like that:

```
SELECT DATE(now()) AS sysformat
     , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%W %M %D %Y, %j\'th day of the year') AS myformat
```